# Why is this Julia snippet so much slower than the Python equivalent? (with dictionaries)

Tags: python, julia

I have the following code in Python Jupyter:

```
n = 10**7
d = {}

%timeit for i in range(n): d[i] = i

%timeit for i in range(n): _ = d[i]

%timeit d[10]
```

with the following times:

```
763 ms ± 19.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
692 ms ± 3.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
39.5 ns ± 0.186 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

and this on Julia

```
using BenchmarkTools
d = Dict{Int64, Int64}()
n = 10^7
r = 1:n

@btime begin
    for i in r
        d[i] = i
    end
end
    
@btime begin
    for i in r
        _ = d[i]
    end
end

@btime d[10]
```

with times:

```
  2.951 s (29999490 allocations: 610.34 MiB)
  3.327 s (39998979 allocations: 762.92 MiB)
  20.163 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

What I am not quite able to understand is why the Julia one seems to be so much slower in dictionary value assignation and retrieval in a loop (first two tests), but at the same time is so much faster in single key retrieval (last test). It seems to be 4 times slower when in a loop, but twice as fast if not in a loop. I'm new to Julia, so I am not sure if I am doing something un-optimal or if this is somehow expected.

Comment: Why are you using a float `10.0`? And why is the Python code the only version that casts to int?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, no good reason for any of the two. The int conversion is because I had a memory of power operation on an int returning a float, not sure if it happens in some other language or I just had it wrong the whole time. Corrected it anyway in case somebody else looks at it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are benchmarking in a top-level scope you have to interpolate variables in `@btime` with `$` so the way to benchmark your code is:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> d = Dict{Int64, Int64}()
Dict{Int64, Int64}()

julia> n = 10^7
10000000

julia> r = 1:n
1:10000000

julia> @btime begin
           for i in $r
               $d[i] = i
           end
       end
  842.891 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime begin
           for i in $r
               _ = $d[i]
           end
       end
  618.808 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime $d[10]
  6.300 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
10
```

Timing for Python 3 on the same machine in Jupyter Notebook is:

```
n = int(10.0**7)
d = {}
%timeit for i in range(n): d[i] = i
913 ms ± 87.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit for i in range(n): _ = d[i]
816 ms ± 92.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit d[10]
50.2 ns ± 2.97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

However, for the first operation I assume you rather wanted to benchmark this:

```
julia> function f(n)
           d = Dict{Int64, Int64}()
           for i in 1:n
               d[i] = i
           end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime f($n)
  1.069 s (72 allocations: 541.17 MiB)
```

against this:

```
def f(n):
    d = {}
    for i in range(n):
        d[i] = i
%timeit f(n)
1.18 s ± 65.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It should also be noted that using a specific value of `n` can be misleading as Julia and Python are not guaranteed to resize their collections at the same moments and to the same new sizes (in order to store a dictionary you normally allocate more memory than needed to avoid hash collisions and here actually a specific value of tested `n` might matter).

#### EDIT

Note that if I declare global variables as `const` all is fast, as then the compiler can optimize the code (it knows the types of the values bound to global variables cannot change); therefore then using `$` is not needed:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> const d = Dict{Int64, Int64}()
Dict{Int64, Int64}()

julia> const n = 10^7
10000000

julia> const r = 1:n
1:10000000

julia> @btime begin
           for i in r
               d[i] = i
           end
       end
  895.788 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime begin
           for i in $r
               _ = $d[i]
           end
       end
  582.214 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime $d[10]
  6.800 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
10
```

If you are curious what are the benefits of having a native support for threading here is a simple benchmark (this functionality is a part of the language):

```
julia> Threads.nthreads()
4

julia> @btime begin
           Threads.@threads for i in $r
               _ = $d[i]
           end
       end
  215.461 ms (23 allocations: 2.17 KiB)
```

Comment: Thanks, with this the results are much more in line with what I had expected. What is the meaning of 'interpolate variables' here, achieved with $?

Comment: without `$` as you can see in your benchmarks you have hundreds of millions of allocations. The reason is (among other things, but let me point a single one) that Julia supports multi-threading natively. Therefore if you use a global variable the compiler cannot be sure that this variable will not be rebound to a value of different type during the execution of the code by other thread. Thus it does more work than needed (as it must be ready for the variable to be bound to `Any`thing). When you use `$` the value is interpolated into executed code block, so Julia knows its type will not change.